# Run DDL queries in SSDT

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I need to delete hundreds of tables from my database model.

Is is possible to run a script to delete these tables in my SSDT project rather than deleting them manually one by one?

Comment: You can write script that would remove all needed objects from the project (edit sqlproj file and/or delete physical files) and then run publish.

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev Unfortunately this doesn't work for indexes since there are within the table declaration script. My need also included removing indexes without removing the associated tables. I think that I will publish my script in a localdb, run the SQL script then import back the modifications by running a schema compare that should do just fine even if I would prefer a more direct approach.

Answer (score 1):

It is too long for comment already, so I'll answer here. In the `sqlproj` file you have references to the physical files, for example:

```
<Build Include="Schemas\dbo\Tables\tableA.sql" />
```

Usually it has table definition and all indexes inside that file, so if you delete this entry from the proj file, then it will not be included to the project. So, if you delete  references to all tables needed to be dropped and publish then it should work.

Your other script for importing everything to local db, drop tables there and then import it or run compare to import the changes.